# Exporting a csv using component fileDownload of primefaces generates problems with comma separator when data have commas

Tags: java, csv, jsf, primefaces

I have the following problem. I am working with Primefaces, JSF and Java. I am trying to generate a csv file with data of the data base and exporting it with the component p:fileDownload of primefaces. The csv is generated without problems but some of the data are strings with commas init, so the result is that there are separated in different columns. Is there a way of setting another separator? (for example ;) .

The method that generates the byte array is this:

```
public byte[] generateCsv(){
                StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
                data.append("header1, header2, header3\n");
                for (element elem : listElements) {
                    data.append(elem.getCode()+","+elem.getName()+","+elem.getData+"\n");
                }
                byte[] bytes = String.valueOf(data).getBytes();
                return bytes;
}
```

In the frontend, the bean has this method:

```
public StreamedContent exportCsv() {
        try {
            
            byte[] cert = businessBean.generateCsv();
            if (cert != null) {
                InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);
                StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(targetStream, "application/csv", "Example.csv");
                
                return file;
            } else {
               //ERROR
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the button that generates the csv in the xhtml is this one:

```
<p:fileDownload contentDisposition="inline"   value="#{exampleBean.exportCsv()}" />
```

Result:
If the elements of each column are supposed to be:

```
column1= elem1
column2= elem2.1,elem2.2
column3=elem3.1,elem3.2
```

In the file every element appears like.

```
column1= elem1
column2= elem2.1
column3=elem2.2
column4=elem3.1
column5=elem3.2
```

There is a way to set a different separator?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can in PF 7.0 or higher using the `options` attribute!

Fixed: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/48

```xml
<p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tbl" fileName="cars" options="#{view.csvOptions}" />
```

And your Options class looks like this to set to colon (:) for example...

```java
public CSVOptions getCsvOptions() {
    CSVOptions options = new CSVOptions();
    options.setDelimiterChar(":");
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question, dataExporter isnt just for dataTable componente? Is there a way to use it with the method exportCsv of my example?

Comment: If you really are hand generating a CSV why not use Apache Commons CSV? It will handle escaping your CSV correctly even columns that contain commas in them!

Comment: Yes you are right @Melloware, the correct answer was using an API, in my case I used openCSV, thank you

Answer (score 0):

in Primefaces 11 you can't set the delimiter anymore.
But maybe

```
public CSVOptions getCsvOptions() {
    // delimiter = ;
    return CSVOptions.EXCEL_NORTHERN_EUROPE;
}
```

does what you need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).